# Not getting server response when passed as bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a controller where I pass direct Bean and @valid annotation to validate.  I have created a custom annotation and added it to each field in the bean. It validates but doesn't give messages from a custom exception handler. Next, if I don't pass bean and pass request param in for every field then it gives proper response from a custom exception handler.

Adding screenshots.[image]

You can see `/group` gives the response of validation when passed as `@RequestParam` and `/check` doesn't give a response message just gives 400 request code.

I have added a response message in custom exception handler[image]

You can see the message passed in constraints violation exception. I Have created custom annotation which just validates special characters nothing else. It works for RequestParam.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So here I resolved the issue with removing the @Valid annotation and added this code

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<ProcessDefination>> violations = validator.validate(processDefination);
            if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
              throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If `400` is in response maybe the problem is not in `@Valid` annotation just `Group` is interpreted as a bad parameter. Try deleting this annotation does 400 still appear?

One thing I don't understand is that you are creating a GET only with @Valid annotation maybe try adding also `@RequestParam` to it. What exactly is Group bean in context of this endpoint?

[EDIT: added as answer because of low rep]

Comment: if I pass the valid data it comes in the group bean